# Having trouble with overfitting in simple R logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, data-analysis, logistic-regression, correlation

I am a newbie to R and I am trying to perform a logistic regression on a set of clinical data.
My independent variable is AGE, TEMP, WBC, NLR, CRP, PCT, ESR, IL6, and TIME.
My dependent variable is binomial CRKP.

After using glm.fit, I was given this error message:

```
glm.fit <- glm(CRKP ~ AGE + TEMP + WBC + NLR + CRP + PCT + ESR, data = cv, family = binomial, subset=train)

Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

I searched up potential problems and used the corrplot function to see if there is multicollinearity that could potentially result in overfitting.

This is what I have as the plot. [image: Correlation Plot]

Correlation plot shows that my ESR and PCT variable are highly correlated. Similarly, CRP and IL6 are highly correlated. But they are all important clinical indicators I would like to include in the model.

I tried to use the VIF to selectively discard variables, but wouldn't that be biased and also I would have to sacrifice some of my variables of interest.

Does anyone know what I can do? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: How many observations does this mode utilise? Binomial GLM can have a perfect fit with only a handful of predictors depending on your number of observations

Comment: I have 51 observations in total.

Comment: See these: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336424/issue-with-complete-separation-in-logistic-regression-in-r

Answer (score 1):

You have a multicollinearity problem but don't want to drop variables. In this case you can use Partial Least Squares (PLS) or Principal Component Regression  (PCR).